# Fuel Expected Begin Array but was Begin Object

Tags: android, kotlin, deserialization, response

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm still learning how to get an object respose but I'm having the following exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Here's the Json Result:

```
{"Success":"1","Message":"True","Items":[{"Id":3,"Name":"AndroidVersion","Value":"1"},{"Id":4,"Name":"IOSVersion","Value":"1.0"},{"Id":5,"Name":"AndroidForceUpdate","Value":"true"}]}
```

Here's the model class

```
data class MobileConfiguration(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val value: String
) {


class Deserializer : ResponseDeserializable<Array<MobileConfiguration>> {
    override fun deserialize(content: String): Array<MobileConfiguration>? = Gson().fromJson(content, Array<MobileConfiguration>::class.java)
}

}
```

And here's the Call:

```
url.httpPost(listOf(Pair("key", ""))).responseObject(MobileConfiguration.Deserializer()) { request, response, result ->

        //val (people, err) = result.get()
        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {
                val ex = result.getException()
                Log.wtf("ex", "is " + ex)
            }
            is Result.Success -> {

                val (config, err) = result
                //Add to ArrayList
                config?.forEach { configuration ->
                    mobileConfigurations.add(configuration)
                }

                println(mobileConfigurations)
            }
        }
    }
```

What Am i doing wrong please if anybody can help

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the model class.
You assume that the `MobileConfiguration` array is directly under the response class, however, actually, it is under the `Items` object.

So instead of using `Array<MobileConfiguration>` as a `responseObject`, you should use other class as a container like:

```
data class MobileConfigurationResponse(
    val success: String,
    val message: String,
    val items: Array<MobileConfiguration>
)
```

and then you can get the array like this:

```
    val (config, err) = result.items
```